# How to draw a rectangle between "datetime" data type and a numeric data type in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

assume I have X,Y

```
x=[03/01/2017,24/01/2017]% datetime type
y=[1000,2000] % numeric value
```

How can I draw a rectangle between those "coordinates" I am having trouble since one of them its DateTime value and the other one is numeric. using a plot function?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The date time can't be treated as coordinates. If you are so sure to plot the rectangle you may need to convert the date time into a serial date number...

```
    x = datenum(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
x = datetime([2017,2017],[1,1],[3,24]); % x = [03/01/2017,24/01/2017]
y = [1000,2000];
fill(x([1,2,2,1]),y([1,1,2,2]),'red')
```

It doesn't matter that x is datetime and y is numeric

Comment: How did you converted x to the data that you wrote? I cant edit my code to what you wrote,I got the 2X1 matrix of x(datetime) and 2X1 matrix of y numeric.

Comment: You don't have to convert x if it's already is in the DateTime format. You only have to run the last line of code if already have x and y defined.